# updating PFObjects that have been savedEventually but have not been sent to Parse yet

Tags: ios, parse-platform, updating, pfobject, pinning

I have a PFObject (called pfObject) I am saving using

```
[pfObject saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                        if (succeeded) {
                            if (pfObject.objectId) {
                                do some stuff
                            }
```

There are times when I may want to update this PFObject after it has been saved, but before a network connection may have been established, so that the modified PFObject, not the original version on which I had called saveEventually, get transmitted.  I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this.  I was wondering whether, if I pin it, and then make changes to the pinned object, that when the network connection is established the altered, pinned object might be the one that gets transmitted...then on (succeeded) i could unpin it.  I have not yet tried this, but thought I might ask before I did to see if anyone could explain the best approach to this problem.

note: another person asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126862/syncing-local-state-and-remote-state-parse-with-poor-connectivity), but got no relevant answer

Comment: I think you can call `saveEventually` as many times as you like. The last version saved is the one that will be stored when a connection is established.

Comment: how is this possible if an objectID hasn't yet been assigned?  or is an objectID assigned when I pin an object?

Comment: As long as you use the same `PFObject` instance Parse will work it out, but if you want it to work between executions then you need to pin it. Generally though you should rarely need to access the actual object Id as you can just use the PFObject itself anywhere where you need a pointer/reference

Comment: It seems you are right.  See the description [here](http://blog.parse.com/learn/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/)

Comment: I will post an answer once I've verified by testing

Comment: ps. the reason I want to access the objectID is that I am using CoreData to store my object graph, and only pushing some stuff up to Parse...I need to know when I can assign the pfObject.objectID to the corresponding item in Core Data